# Consuming a live REST services in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Can you point me to a good and working examples of how to Consume Restful services in web ASP.net. Tutorials, walk-through or any useful material. I just join a company that require me to do that and I am new to ASP.net especially the rest service. I have used many materials and yet not clear.

Help me with the A B C of Rest usage in ASP.net pls

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a code that works with my Rest Servive.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System.Net;


namespace WebTestRestfullService
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public string JS;
        public string resp;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://88.208.232.99:0000");//Dont use this.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/json"));
                //This is wrong too
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Correct/api/"));
                string query = "Correct/api/";//You must get the api refernce correct.
                // HTTP GET
                //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(". ");
                string resp = "";

                var task = client.GetAsync(query).ContinueWith
                    ((taskwithresponse) =>
                        {
                            var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
                            var jsonstr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            jsonstr.Wait();
                            resp = jsonstr.Result;
                        });
                task.Wait();




                Response.Write(resp);
                // string data =  $.parseJSON(lbltest.Text);
                // Session["resp"] = resp;
                // new code

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The challenge and having now is how to pass the data to a html form on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a REST client library that works on all .NET based platforms.

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

There is a sample REST service there that calls another REST service. The service is written for ASP.NET Core so it should help you.